# RuntimeError: Never call result.get() within a task

Tags: python, django, celery

My task (check payment status in Sberbank. If no capture - retry check):

```py
from ....celeryconf import app
from . import client as sberbank
from ...models import Payment, Transaction


@app.task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=60, time_limit=1200)
def check_status_sberbank_task(self, order_id, connection_params):
    sberbank_client = sberbank.Client(auth=(connection_params['login'], connection_params['password']),
                                      sandbox=connection_params['sandbox_mode'])

    response = sberbank_client.payment.get_status(order_id=order_id)

    txn = Transaction.objects.get(token=order_id)
    if response['actionCode'] == 0:

        txn.is_success = True
        txn.save()

        payment = Payment.objects.get(pk=txn.payment_id)
        payment.charge_status = 'fully-charged'
        payment.captured_amount = payment.total
        payment.save()

        return 'Success pay on Sberbank for ' + str(order_id)
    else:
        self.retry(countdown=60)
```

in log file I have:

> ERROR celery.app.trace Task
> saleor.payment.gateways.sberbank.tasks.check_status_sberbank_task[bb384815-4a5b-49d7-bc29-114707f072b1]
> raised unexpected: RuntimeError('Never call result.get() within a
> task!\nSee
> [http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks\n',](http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks%5Cn%27,))
> [PID:26869:Thread-825]
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/korolev/saleor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/trace.py",
> line 385, in trace_task
> R = retval = fun(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/korolev/saleor/saleor/payment/gateways/sberbank/tasks.py", line
> 26, in check_status_sberbank_task
> self.retry(countdown=60)   File "/home/korolev/saleor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/task.py",
> line 715, in retry
> S.apply().get()   File "/home/korolev/saleor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py",
> line 1015, in get
> assert_will_not_block()   File "/home/korolev/saleor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/result.py",
> line 41, in assert_will_not_block
> raise RuntimeError(E_WOULDBLOCK)
>
> RuntimeError: Never call result.get() within a task! See
> http://docs.celeryq.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#task-synchronous-subtasks

How do I fix this error?

Comment: you are providing a default retry time, remove the else part then try again

Comment: Then, if response ['actionCode']> 0, the task will not be called after 60 seconds